# unable to find element inside <figure> tag in Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have the below html source. In selenium webdriver by using below code, when counting the number of webelements containing text 'ABC' it works and returns 1. But when trying to count for texts 'PQR' or 'XYZ', it returns 0.

(1) How can I get 1 for PQR/XYZ?
(2) I want to get list of values of all elements with class="meter-value". ie. 0%, 100% and so on.

Please can someone help? I am unable to figure out.

`List<WebElement>textDemo= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'ABC')]"));
System.out.println("Number of web elements: " +textDemo.size());`

HTML:-

```
<div data-reactroot="">
    <div class="object-bar">
        <img id="spinner" src="data:image/gif;base64,XXXXlhIAAgAPUmANnZ2fX19efn5" hidden="">
        <a href="SOME URL" class="abc-link">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"></svg>
            <!-- react-text: 7 --> 
            ABC Home
            <!-- /react-text -->
            </a>
        </div>
    <div class="body">
        <figure>
            <div class="gauge">
                <div class="meter"></div>
                <div class="meter-value-container">
                    <div class="meter-value">0%</div>
                </div>
                </div>
            <figcaption>
                <!-- react-text: 15 --> 
                PQR
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <div>(40960 of 40960 left)</div>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <div class="gauge">
                <div class="meter"></div>
                <div class="meter-value-container">
                    <div class="meter-value">100%</div>
                </div>
                </div>
            <figcaption>
            <!-- react-text: 23 --> 
            XYZ
            <!-- /react-text -->
            <div>(200 of 200 left)</div>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to get all the caption nodes, try this xpath,

```
//*[@class='meter-value']/parent::div/parent::div/following::figcaption
```

If you like to search by contains text,then try this ,

`//figcaption[contains(.,'PQR')]` - This should return 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

text() method does not ork if there is HTML element parallel to text. Try using '.' to get text. Try as belo:

```
List<WebElement>textDemo= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[local-name()='figure']"));
System.out.println("Number of web elements: " +textDemo.size());
```

Comment: Thank you, however it still returns me 0 only.

Comment: Does it identify figure tag if found by tagName?

Comment: No, it does not. I tried below, it returns 0

      List<WebElement>textDemo= driver.findElements(By.tagName("figure"));
      System.out.println("Number of web elements: " +textDemo.size());

Comment: Is it still a problem? I have updated the solution. Please try it. check if figure tag is identified

Answer (score 0):

**For 1 question**

PQR and XYZ - `//figcaption`
[image: PQR and XYZ]

Only XYZ - `//figcaption[contains(.,"XYZ")]`
[image: Only XYZ]

Only PQR `//figcaption[contains(.,"PQR")]`
[image: PQR]

**For 2 question**

`//div[@class = "meter-value"]`
[image: meter-value]

Comment: Thank you. but somehow it is still not working. I used this.

List<WebElement>textDemo= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'meter-value']"));
System.out.println("Number of web elements: " +textDemo.size());


Result - Number of web elements: 0

Comment: as long as I am working outside the <figure> tag, it works. By.xpath("//div[@class = 'body']")...returns 1.

If I do....By.xpath("//div[@class = 'gauge']"), then it returns 0 only.

Comment: @Sanjay Can you find this xpath on the browser page, via the developer console ? And can you show me site (link) ?

Comment: for the first "meter-value", xpath from developer console is

//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/figure[1]/div/div[2]/div

Comment: @Sanjay, no, you need to enter xpath, in the search bar https://pastenow.ru/3847edb023756a9c2f82e250f9e1edcd

Comment: Sorry Vitalii, I am not getting what you are asking. Pardon me! Are you saying search bar in the developer console, then I dont see a search bar. And the link you have sent, I dont know what I need to do in it

Comment: one more thing, you use double code in your xpath i.e "meter-value". But it gives error to me. So I change it to single code like 'meter-value'. Is it the problem?

Comment: This is possible, since the search for driver is used in this way everywhere in the examples .find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Some text"]')  https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210067/discussion-between-sanjay-and-vitalii).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working by using the `WebDriverWait` just before the code as below. Now it finds the elements.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='meter-value']")));
```